# How to measure the actual bits of data transfer over a USB cable?

Tags: usb, oscilloscope, cables, usb-device, bit-rate

**EDIT 1**

I am doing an investigation and I have to do an experiment and write a report based on different USB speeds.

**Edit 2**

To explain my investigation again, I am trying to measure the rate of data transfer of USB 2 and USB 3 by looking at the number of bits that transfer over the cable (I will connect the USB drive using an extension cable so I can probe the wires). I want to know how I can do this.

**Edit 3**

I am doing an investigation to see whether the the packaging information is actually what we get during normal use. I remember reading on the USB website that those values "may not be exact" (something like that).

**Edit 4**

**My Project Brief: By probing the USB cable measure the rate of data transfer across USB 2 and USB 3 by looking at the bits that are transferred.**

**Original:**

I have a USB drive which is connected to my laptop via a USB extension cable. I did this so that I can cut the wire casing and and expose the D+ and D- (differential pair) wires. I read online that this is where the data is flowing from. I want to know how I can use some device (other than a digital oscilloscope) to probe the wires and count the number of bits of data transfer. I am guessing that the bits would transfer as either High or Low voltages. So is there a way to count the number of High voltage passes as that would be the number of bits that transfer?

**If I have anything wrong here, please let me know. Any methods are welcome including analogue oscilloscopes. I need to compare the rate of transfer of bits so I can find the actual rate of data transfer of the USB**

Comment: Actually the USB datalink layer is well documented in the [USB Specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb20_docs/); no need to guess. Note that bit stuffing is used to ensure that there is always a transition after a certain number of periods, so not every bit seen on the datalink is part of the upper lever protocols.

Comment: Lower-speed USB could be visible on an analog 20MHz scope, but USB2 or above will not be. What's the purpose of this or is it just curiosity?

Comment: Without a high speed scope that is capable of decoding USB itself, everything else is guessing. You could hook up a frequency counter to get *some* feeling about data rates, but it really depends on what is transferred.

Comment: You exclude the only tool that can do this - the only tool that exists and is _specifically constructed_ to do _exactly_ this. Your question is thus a pointless mind-game.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I am going to transfer normal data files like word docs, video, mp3 etc. What type of frequency counters could I use and how exactly would these work?

Comment: @Lakshya: _Why_ do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @pipe I don't want to use digital oscilloscopes because I can't. They are too expensive and I don't see myself ever using them again. Do you know where (I live in Bangkok) or how it's possible to rent them?

Comment: @Transistor I am doing an investigation and I have to do an experiment and write a report based on different USB speeds.

Comment: @Lakshya: Then write that **in your question**. Actually put the project brief in your question. You may be going about it with the wrong approach. Monitoring the frequency itself might tell you the bus speed but not the data transfer rate as there will be message headers and wrappers, etc., which means that the data transfer rate will be less than the frequency suggests.

Comment: You don't need (or want) an oscilloscope. What you need is a USB protocol analyzer. One popular line is made by [Total Phase](http://www.totalphase.com/protocols/usb/), but there are many others. You can probably rent one for the duration of your project.

Comment: @DaveTweed What is a USB Protocol Analyser and what exactly does it do? What will it analyse and give me?

Comment: Highly recommend getting Axelson's USB Complete -- https://www.amazon.com/USB-Complete-Fourth-Developers-Guides/dp/1931448086

Comment: @DaveTweed I just searched that the speed of USB 3.0 is 480 megabits per second. Is that the same as 480 MHz?

Comment: @Lakshya: Your edit still doesn't give enough information. Please write the complete project brief in your question. Everyone (including yourself) is guessing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why try to measure it rather than taking the numbers from the USB spec at face value? Especially if it's not hardware you've built and you don't really have the right equipment.

Comment: @pjc50 I am doing an investigation to see whether the the packaging information is actually what we get during normal use. I remember reading on the USB website that those values "may not be exact" (something like that).

Comment: I think you're pretty confused about what you want to measure and why. What do you mean by "packaging information"?  A few seconds on wikipedia tells you that USB 3 is not 480 Mb/s. You're doing all this because you think you read on a website some time ago that the values "may not be exact"? I assure you, they will be exact.

Comment: For this kind of thing it will be *far* easier to do the USB packet capture with timestamps on the computer: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB - so you can look at the upper layer, rather than trying to count bits at the low level.

Comment: I would think the cable would be the LAST place you'd look to figure out what you're trying to know.  This is one of the things that protocol analyzers are for.  Further, if you know what arrives at the host machine, and what was sent, how long it took to get from point a to point b, and the protocol used, its probably safe to assume that everything travelled through the cable.

Comment: @Transistor I have added edits to the question now. Is it more clear now? Am I still missing anything?

Comment: Yes. You are still missing the project brief. You appear to have been tasked with measuring data transfer rate via USB and you have decided that the way to do this is by monitoring the signals in the cable and now you are blind to every other solution. Nearly everyone else here would measure the data transfer rate by using software running on the PC instead of trying to measure it on the wires. Were you _told_ to measure the signals on the data lines? **Post the project brief** and then we'll be able to help. You've wasted a lot of people's time already by not doing this.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to tell from your question what exactly you're trying to do, but if your USB bus is working to the point it can send data, you almost certainly don't need to see anything on the phy level. It's very easy to disturb USB by connecting something to it, especially at high speed, and you will need a good scope/analyser to see the actual transfers from your drive (D+/D- lines will be clocked at 450 MHz, so you'll need multy-GHz sampling to be able to see anything). Even simple pulse counting is not a trivial task at this frequency, and you won't be able to deduce bit count from counting pulses in NRZI code.

If you need to monitor, profile or debug data transfers, you should use corresponding facilities of your host controller. In Linux, you have `usbmon` for this:

```
modprobe usbmon
cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/0u > usb.log
```

I bet there are similar facilities in other OS as well. For Windows, [USBLyzer](http://www.usblyzer.com/) suggested by @Naz in comments seems to offer similar functions. It seems to be paid software with 33-day trial period.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am very new to this sort of stuff so could you please explain what you mean by "multy-GHz sampling" and "pulse counting". Also, what is NRZI code?

Comment: Perhaps you could start by reading Wikipedia articles on [NRZI code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-return-to-zero), [sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28signal_processing%29) and [counters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_%28digital%29)

Comment: If I were to buy a digital oscilloscope, what would the exact specs of it need to be so that I could see the actual waveform of the bits being transferred in the USB cable. I would be testing upto USB 3.0. Does it just need to be up to 450 MHz?

Comment: Do you actually have to physically probe the signals? There should be some software programs that track data transfers and all the USB communications (USBLyzer). Also, you could simply write a program to perform transfers and then collect statistics on how much data you transferred at a given time duration.

Comment: USB 3 goes into much higher frequencies, 2.5GHz or so. You'll need several samples per bit to see a waveform, so you'll need something like a 10GHz analyzer, which is AFAIK expensive as hell.

Comment: @Naz I do need to probe my USB cable. But what hardware would I need for this?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I don't understand, you said it has 2.5GHz frequency, but I need a 10 GHz analyser? Does analyser mean the same as the Bandwidth? And what about the sample rate?

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal Think about this: if you measure a 2.5GHz sine wave at 2.5GHz frequency, you'll always measure the same value, so you will see a flat line. How many points per period to you think you need to see the sine correctly?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Also, to be able to see the waveform of the bits being transferred, does the bandwidth matter more, or the Samples/sec?

Comment: @Naz Does USBLyzer show me the speed of the data transfer? Does it tell me the number of bits of data that have been transferred and the rate? I couldn't find this on their website.

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal How do I know? I don't even have Windows to begin with.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Ok, sorry about that. So in my case, what is more important: bandwidth or sample rate? Which one needs to be 10GHz? Also, I just searched the speed of USB 3 and it was 480 Megabits/sec. Is that the same as 480MHz?

Comment: I do not know. They offer a 33 day trial.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your university happens to have a USB 3 hardware analyzer in the lab, or you can talk the manufacturer into loaning one, or you want to spend a few semesters building some custom test gear based on a very high performance FPGA and whatever lowest level interface chips you can find, hardware approaches to this problem are basically not workable.

That leaves you two choices:

1) Analyze the specs and write up what you are able to learn theoretically

2) Conduct tests *measured by software* and extend measurable metrics like packet timestamps and condition codes, by means of knowledge of the spec, to a *reconstruction* of what happened on the wire.   You may be able to do this with tools like wireshark, or the USB analyzer built into some versions of Windows.  If those are insufficient you might also consider instrumenting a customized Linux kernel.

Or perhaps you can convince your supervisor to drop the requirement to USB full speed, which you probably can look at in detail with a few hundred dollar oscilloscope, and perhaps even capture continuously with a relatively affordable logic analyzer setup.

Comment: Thanks for the well-rounded answer. I wanted to know what you mean by choice 2). It sounds useful but I don't understand what you are saying. I do have a Hantek 6022BE which has 250MS/s real-time sampling, 20MHz-80MHz bandwidth. Could I use this? If yes, then how would I do this?

Comment: That scope would only work for the old low-speed and full-speed modes (which are still used by many devices - keyboard, mice, most MCUs, serial converters, etc), and even then it is going to be rather hard to capture enough to make sense of what you are seeing.  You will probably do far better with a purely software approach.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I got when I used my oscilloscope to measure the data transfer on the wires. I remember that I used the USB D+ and ground wires. Link: http://imgur.com/a/m9X9v

Comment: I'm going to have to join those getting rather frustrated with your refusal to listen to the repeated explanations of why an ordinary oscilloscope **cannot accomplish your original goal**.  Either switch your goals to a lower speed USB mode, or **stop wasting everyone's time** asking how you can use your scope to do something it cannot do.

Comment: I know it is an old question, but I'm amazed no one called the OP on it.  USB(of any speed) is differential.  This means that using the D+ to ground would not of worked anyway, even if the Oscope he was using had the bandwidth for it. Using that 6022BE you MIGHT be able to measure USB1 signaling by tying the ground leads together and put one probe each on USB- and USB+.  You are not going to measure USB2 let alone USB3 with it. USB3 is 5Gbits, which works out to about 2.4Ghz, which means a minimum of a 5Gsps scope and you really want 10Gsps to be safe.